# openSUSE 12.3 KDE Lan networking

Tags: linux, networking, router, lan, opensuse

I've just installed openSUSE 12.3 on my PC and faced a problem 
I have a DSL connection with Tp-link Td-8811 modem. I configured my modem on PPPoE so it will connect to Internet automatically whenever it's available 
(in Windows and Ubunto the computer is connected without doing anything) 
but in SUSE there is no connection. The LAN LED on my modem is off and I couldn't find any LAN connection or setting in SUSE to fix that.

Comment: suse KDE or suse gnome?

Comment: KDE , mentioned in the title btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved
for anybody that is here by search here is my solution 
Yast > network devices > network setting > overview > edit > in configuration men 
in address tab you can chose either dynamic or manual address